# get updated value in jquery inline editing?

Tags: jquery

I can't get updated value of text box in following codes.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='jquery.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#edit").click(function(){
                    if($(this).html() == "Edit"){
                        $(this).html("Update");
                        var my_val = $(this).parents().find("#name").html();
                        var new_html = "<input type='text' value='" + my_val + "' />";
                        $(this).parents().find("#name").html(new_html);
                        return false;
                    }else{
                        if($(this).html() == "Update"){
                            var txt_box = $(this).parents().find("#name").html();
                            alert($(txt_box).val());
                        }
                    }
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table id='test_table'>
            <tr>
                <td id='name'>My Name</td>
                <td><a href='#' id='edit'>Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
   var txt_box = $(this).parents().find("#name").html();
```

to

```
var txt_box = $(this).parents().find("#name > input");
```

That's because the first will always result in :

```
<input type="text" value="My Name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.html()` on this line:

```
var txt_box = $(this).parents().find("#name").html();
```

And the $() wrapper in the alert. So you have:

```
var txt_box = $(this).parents().find("#name");
alert(txt_box.val());
```

Answer (score 0):

May be it will be better and simpler to use jquery plugin like [jquery-in-place-editor](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-in-place-editor/) (see demo [here](http://jquery-in-place-editor.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demo/index.html))?